# GPS tracker for pet location history?

Tags: cats, safety, gps

I am curious if anyone has experience with GPS trackers for pet (cat in my case) location history. We're interested in knowing where she likes to wander, but not in locating her in realtime remotely.

What features are useful, and which features sound good on paper but end up not working or being helpful?

Comment: I would try to find some kind of small and cheap android device. Google Location History seems exactly what you want.

Comment: Websearching "GPS pet tracker" finds commercial products for the purpose. I have no experience with any of them.

Answer (score 3):

I have first hand experience with one such device.  From a technical standpoint (and avoiding the shopping aspect of the question) most of the options seem to deliver similar features and performance.

We live in a house by the edge of town, and we're surrounded by meadows and forest.  That should have been a clear sign for me that the collar wouldn't be a great idea: the GPS trackers are *fairly* bulky, and they stick out quite a bit from the fur.  When Max, our cat, came back home for the first time without his tracker, I had to go fetch it.  It took a long time to get somewhere in the middle of the woods, and as the device is accurate only to about 6ft it was hard to find under brushes and branches.  The same thing happened 3 times, until we finally decided not to fit it anymore, and sell it off.